# Subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

> $\{(x,y) \vert x \in \mathbb{Q}, y \notin \mathbb{Q} \}$

I'm am attempting to find the interior, closure, isolated points, and boundary of this set but am running into issues since I am unable to even visualize it. Intuitively it seems like this set is just a scattered set of points in the plane thus every point is an isolated point. The closure would be the plane, but am unsure as to what the boundary would be.

Comment: I guess you need to specify the topology here.

Comment: The "boundary" for sets like this has little intuitive sense beyond "closure minus interior". Have you figured out what the interior is?

Comment: @CheeHan since I'm not given a defined metric, I'm assuming the standard metric.

Comment: @Joppy no, I actually don't know what the interior would be.

Comment: **Hint**: Call the set $A$. Suppose $(x,y)$ is in the interior of the set. Then, we can find an open ball $B \subset A$ centred at $(x,y)$. But then...

Answer (score 0):

This fact should make finding the boundary and the interior pretty straightforward:

The boundary of A in X is the intersection of (the closure of A) with (the closure of (X without A)).

Comment: $\bar{A}$= $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\overline{\mathbb{R}^2\setminus A} = \{(x,y) \vert x \notin \mathbb{Q}, y \in \mathbb{Q} \}$?

Comment: @ElSpiffy: $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus A = \{(x, y) \mid x \notin \mathbb{Q}, y \in \mathbb{Q}\}$, which is the same as $A$ rotated by 90 degrees. Since you know the closure of $A$ is the whole plane, what is the closure of this new set...

Comment: The set that Joppy describes is not exactly the complement of A (for if so, where is (0,0)?), but the idea is on the right track.  You CAN say, however, that the set he describes (let's call it B) is CONTAINED in the complement of A.  If you think carefully about all the points that make up the complement of A, showing that B is a subset if R2\A is straightforward.  THEN, it is quite obvious that the closure of B is R2, and since B in R2\A in R2, then the closure of R2\A must also be R2.  Consequently, the boundary of A is R2 intersect R2 = R2, and the interior of A is R2 without R2; ie empty.